# iOS SpreadsheetView, sheet cut when rotated

Tags: ios, swift, spreadsheet

I have this problem. I need the sheet rotated like in this screenshot.

[image]

So I rotated the UIView (subclassed in `SpreadsheetView` class) with

```
spreadsheetView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
```

and made it `@IBDesignable`, that's why I have the view rotated in storyboard too.

But when the app is launched I have this result:

[image]

As you can see, datas are cropped, and they're cropped starting from the blue border of the view not rotated (see first image, the highlighted rectangle).
How can I fit the datas from the start to the end of the view in the orientation that I need?

The library I'm using is [SpreadsheetView](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView), this is my class:

```
import UIKit
import SpreadsheetView

class TableChartViewController: UIViewController, SpreadsheetViewDataSource {

    var headerString = ["Luogo", "Attività", "Umore", "Tot.", "Alta", "Media", "Bassa"]
    var data = [[String]]()

    @IBOutlet weak var spreadSheetView: SpreadsheetView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        spreadSheetView.dataSource = self
        spreadsheetView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)

        spreadSheetView.register(HeaderCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: HeaderCell.self))
        spreadSheetView.register(TextCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: TextCell.self))
    }

    //sorting funcs
    enum Sorting {
        case ascending
        case descending

        var symbol: String {
            switch self {
            case .ascending:
                return "\u{25B2}" //unicode for black up-pointing triangle
            case .descending:
                return "\u{25BC}" //unicode for black down-pointing triangle
            }
        }
    }
    var sortedColumn = (column: 0, sorting: Sorting.ascending)

    //spreadSheetView funcs
    func numberOfColumns(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {
        return headerString.count
    }

    func numberOfRows(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, widthForColumn column: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }

    func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, heightForRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cell? {
        if case 0 = indexPath.row {
            let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: HeaderCell.self), for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
            cell.label.text = headerString[indexPath.column]

            if case indexPath.column = sortedColumn.column {
                cell.sortArrow.text = sortedColumn.sorting.symbol
            } else {
                cell.sortArrow.text = ""
            }
            cell.setNeedsLayout()

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: TextCell.self), for: indexPath) as! TextCell
            cell.label.text = "Prova"
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, don't know why but it works!

Just put the `SpreadsheetView` in another `UIView` with default class and rotate **just** this one.
Obviously make sure to match dimensions of the `SpreadsheetView` with `UIView` and that's it.

[image: Screen of the app with this workaround]